# Can AsyncEventListener.process wait on value-returning async Callable(s)?

Tags: gemfire, geode

I want to know if it is safe for the `boolean processEvents(final List<AsyncEvent> events)` method of a serial `AsyncEventListener` that needs to use the Geode/GemFire API to wait on a value-returning async task (e.g., a Callable<Boolean>) so that `processEvents` returns true only if the work done in the async task was successful?

Obviously, the point is that I don't want the `AsyncEventListener.processEvents` method to return true (indicating success) if in fact the processing of those events didn't actually succeed. It's just that the processing of the events is happening in another thread.

I do understand that it would be bad for the async task(s) to take very long and tie up the thread on which the AsyncEventListener is processing.

But, other than throughput, is there a danger in doing this kind of thing? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want within your `AsyncEventListener`, the actual thread invoking the callback is independent from the thread executing the actual cache operation, so clients won't notice the "slowness" in your listener.

That said, it's in your best interest to make sure the implementation is able to "keep up" with the rate at which events are added to the queue, otherwise they will start to pile up and the whole cluster might suffer.